# How to create multiple log file for multiple user using log4j.properties

Tags: java, log4j

How to create multiple log file for multiple user. Log files will be generated based on username and username coming from API and store in log4j.property file dynamically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on MDC:
https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback

You can put the username into MDC and then group the log messages based on the MDC key using log4j configuration file.